# Please help me understand this recursion function

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to understand this recursion function and better educate myself on recursion in general. I can't seem to follow how this code does it's thing. I'm hoping someone can walk me through this so I can understand what's going on. This function takes the largest value of an array and checks to see if any combination of numbers add up to this value.

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) {
  arr.sort(function(a,b){  //sort array;
    return a - b;
  });
  console.log('Sorted Array: ['+arr+']');
  var largest = arr.pop();  //grab last value aka largest

  function recursion(target, array){
    if(array.length === 0) {  //if array is empty return boolean
        return target === 0;
    }
    var n = array[0];       //first value of array
    array = array.slice(1);
    console.log('Array: [' +array+']');
    console.log('Target: '+target);
    return recursion(target,array) || recursion(target - n, array);   //not exactly sure about this ???
  }
  return recursion(largest,arr);  //call recursion function
}

console.log(ArrayAdditionI([4,6,21,10,20,1]));
```

Here are the results I get from calling this. I've commented on them to show where I get lost.

```
Sorted Array: [1,4,6,10,20,21] 
Array: [4,6,10,20]  //first value and largest value removed
Target: 21          //target highest value
Array: [6,10,20]    //first value removed again
Target: 21          //still 21
Array: [10,20]      //another value removed
Target: 21
Array: [20]         //last value in array
Target: 21
Array: []           //empty array.. Why did this not return a false???
Target: 21          
Array: []           //why is it doing this twice?
Target: 11          //where in the world did this come from. I see 21 - 10 but how did that happen?
Array: [20]         //When did this value get added back to the array?
Target: 15          //Totally lost at this point...
Array: []
Target: 15
Array: []
Target: 5
Array: [10,20]      //Where are these values coming from?
Target: 17
Array: [20]
Target: 17          //why does the target keep changing??
Array: []          
Target: 17
Array: []           
Target: 7
Array: [20]
Target: 11          //from 17 to 7 then back to 11?
Array: []
Target: 11
Array: []           //Empty arrays still not returning false??
Target: 1
Array: [6,10,20]    //No idea how these combinations are being generated.
Target: 20
Array: [10,20]
Target: 20
Array: [20]
Target: 20
Array: []
Target: 20
true                //Right answer but how?
```

Comment: _"and checks to see if any combination of numbers add up to this value"_ Where ?

Answer (score 4):

I hope this gets you on the right track:

> Array: []           //empty array.. Why did this not return a false???

Because the array wasn't empty when the check was done. It became empty when the `slice` call removed the last item. The calls that follow will return false when array is empty going into the function.

> Array: []           //why is it doing this twice?

Because of the expression `recursion(target,array) || recursion(target - n, array)`. Each of them are called with an array with a single item, and will show an empty array when they remove the item.

> Target: 11          //where in the world did this come from. I see 21
>   - 10 but how did that happen?

That's the `recursion(target - n, array)` being called when `target == 21` and `n == 10`.

> Array: [20]         //When did this value get added back to the array?

It's not added back, it's a different array. The recursion has reached its limit and it taking a step back to a previous state to try the next possibility.

> Target: 15          //Totally lost at this point...

That's the `recursion(target - n, array)` being called when `target == 21` and `n == 6`.

> Array: [10,20]      //Where are these values coming from?

That's another step back. Each recursion level stores the state on the stack, so that it can back up to the previous state.

> Target: 17          //why does the target keep changing??

Because the code is trying different combinations into the path of the `recursion(target - n, array)` call. The function is called with a new value for `target`.

> Array: []           //Empty arrays still not returning false??

Yes, they do. Each empty array ends one possible combination, and makes the code back up and try the next combination.

> Array: [6,10,20]    //No idea how these combinations are being generated.

By tracking back to the state where the array was `[4,6,10,20]` and slicing off the `4`.

> true                //Right answer but how?

By going into every possible combination and out again until the right one was found.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can consider it as an answer, but check it out.
This is your own code without hacks and with better diagnostics:

```
function ArrayAdditionI(arr) {
    arr.sort(function (a, b) { //sort array;
        return a - b;
    });
    console.log('Sorted Array: [' + arr + ']');
    var largest = arr.pop(); //grab last value aka largest

    function recursion(target, array, level) {
        level++;
        console.log("Level: "+level);
        console.log("Entering: " + target + " [" + array + "]");
        if (array.length === 0) { //if array is empty return boolean
            console.log("Array empy, is target 0? " + (target === 0));
            result = (target === 0);
        } else {
            var n = array[0]; //first value of array
            array = array.slice(1);
            console.log('Calling return: target=' + target + ', n=' + n + ', ' + '[' + array + ']');
            var result = recursion(target, array, level);
            if (result === true){ 
                console.log("Path 1: true");
            } else {
                result = recursion(target - n, array, level);
                console.log("Path 2: "+result);
            }
        }
        console.log('Returning level='+level+': '+result);
        console.log(); //spacer
        level--;
        return result;
    }
    return recursion(largest, arr, 0); //call recursion function
}
```

Comment: Add that `array = array.slice(1)` creates a copy of the array without the first member, so each recursive call has it's own instance of the array.

Comment: Thank you very much Nagh! I have been looking over the logs over and over and think it's beginning to make some sense. Your logs are much clearer than mine. I still have a few things to work out but this is helping.

Comment: RobG your comment cleared up some confusion. Thank you